# how to remove a file in /etc when rc.sysinit is executing?

Tags: linux, bash

I want to remove a file when rc.sysinit is executing I've written something like following :

> yes | rm /etc/anImportantFileWhichBelongsToSystem

I guess the parent user for executing rc.sysinit is "root" which means it can do whatever he wants but in my case I can't remove a simple file from hard disk and the error is not shown the attribute of file is :
700

what should I do?

Comment: Why not use `rm -f` instead of the `yes` pipe?

Comment: or use /bin/rm instead of the the alias rm ?

Comment: @Mel_Burslan if he's running a script as startup (hinted by rc.sysinit context) he's running original Bourne shell (comaptible) which doesn't have aliases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. as @Daniel Beck said, you really should use rm -f for this. You don't need the odd (but working) yes-pipe hack.
2. The filesystem may not be writable at that point. Have you tested to see if you can create a file at that point in the script? `touch /etc/testfile` or so, just to make sure it's mounted and writable.
3. There may be extended attributes on the file. Extended attributes are things that override root privileges. What does `lsattr file` say.

Answer (score 1):

try moving it to `/dev/null` or `unlink` or `echo  :> /etc/anImportantFileWhichBelongsToSystem`

Answer (score 1):

Possible problem is that the filesystem might not be mounted and/or not mounted as R/W at that point.  You may have to do this later after rc.sysinit has completed.

Comment: rc.sysinit is usually in /etc, so it's probably mounted. you may want to add "not mounted writable"